# How to get response from nodejs server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, angular8

In my application I want to get response from nodejs server. if I enter already registered mail id I want to get "User already exists" message on browser console.log in register.component.ts. How do it?
Many times tried but not able to findout. Please anyone help.

user.js://server

```
    users.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    const today = new Date()
    const userData = {
        first_name: req.body.first_name,
        last_name: req.body.last_name,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
        created: today
    }

    User.findOne({
            email: req.body.email
        })
        //TODO bcrypt
        .then(user => {

            if (!user) {
                User.create(userData)
                    .then(user => {
                        const payload = {
                            _id: user._id,
                            first_name: user.first_name,
                            last_name: user.last_name,
                            email: user.email
                        }
                        let token = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.SECRET_KEY, {
                            expiresIn: 1440
                        })
                        res.json({ token: token })
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        res.send('error: ' + err)
                    })
            } else {
                res.json({ error: 'User already exists' })
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.send('error: ' + err)
        })
})
```

authentication.service.ts:

```
  public register(user: TokenPayload): Observable<any> {
    const base = this.http.post(`/users/register`, user)

    const request = base.pipe(
      map((data: TokenResponse) => {
        if (data.token) {
          this.saveToken(data.token)
        }
        return data;
      })
    )

    return request;
  }
```

register.component.ts:

```
register() {
   this.auth.register(this.credentials).subscribe(
     () => {
       this.router.navigateByUrl('/profile')
     },
     err => {
       console.error(err); // how to get  error message like "User already exits"

     }
   )
 }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Just I want to show alert message If I type already registered mail id on register form.     <button (click)="register()">Register</button>

Comment: Full source code here: https://github.com/ArjunAranetaCodes/MoreCodes-Youtube/tree/master/mean-mongodb-login-reg

Comment: @TomSlabbaert:  console.error(err); //  Here how to get  error message like "User already exits"

Comment: @TomSlabbaert: Inside the register function I want to get response message like "User already exits" in console.log(err); (or) console.error(err);

Comment: @TomSlabbaert: Clearly I am explaining: How to show this error message in my browser on when I type the already registered email again.  [ otherthings working fine except this error message]

Comment: Have you looked into flash messages? example: https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash

Comment: @JasonRoman: How we can use it?

Comment: You can set a flash message (exists in session only on next request) and then have code that displays flash messages in your templates